# Which formats can I use for animated 3D objects

Tags: iphone, 3d, augmented-reality, 3d-model

.. in order to use in augmented reality application on iphone?

I have an app working like that; camera detects the marker and then it places an object related to that marker. However the object is not animated. It stands there. Of course i can move the object programmatically but i don't want to do that. What i want is the object has animation itself. I searched but i can't find exact file format. There are .obj files (not animated itself, is it true?), .mtl files, .anm files .etc. If the format is one of them, then can you give me an example model?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Definitely MD2 is your best choice. I have integrated jPCT-AE and Vuforia and it works like a charm. AFAIK MD2 is best for animated models mainly because it can store the key-frame animation in itself and you can have any kind of animation with it at almost no cost.

Here is a test video:

http://youtu.be/chsHh0pEhzw

If you have more question do not hesitate ;)

Comment: jPCT 3D engine is for android only ? Do you know the 3D engine  for iphone ?

Answer (score 1):

You should specify what AR SDK/platform you are using to create the iPhone application you are talking about. That being said, for many of the common AR SDK available the MD2 format is often used to display animated models (either with a built in render engine or with example code that shows how to use the MD2 format with that SDK):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD2_(file_format)

http://www.junaio.com/develop/docs/documenation/general/3dmodels/

OBJ (Wavefront) files do not support animation.

Comment: Currently I'm using the vuforia sdk. I'm able  to animate an object using opengles methods but I don't want it. I need an animated obj. I'll continue my research based on the information you gave. Thanks for answer. Any help is also welcomed:)

Comment: You may want to try Metaio. It can handle md2 and obj out of the box and can be expanded to provide your own custom rendering code if you need that (to support another format, work directly with opengl, etc). One drawback from Vuforia is that the free version is watermarked, but if you build your app through Junaio (an AR browser built with Metaio) you can use it without the watermark. http://www.metaio.com/products/mobile-sdk/

Comment: I've researched and tried 5-6 sdk then I decided that vuforia is the most suitable sdk for developing augmented reality applications. So I started to use it. In my opinion vuforia is really good at detect markers and compatible with opengles. Therefore I don't think Metaio yet. Still thank you for comments.